# Bigquery job expiring before ending the rows iteration

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I'm iterating through a big query result using the rows iterator object that the bigquery client returns. The problem is that it breaks when the script processing the rows takes too much time (more than 24 hours) because the temporal table expires.

This is what I'm doing right now to iterate the results:

```
job = self.client.query(query)
rows_iterator = job.result()
rows_iterator.client.list_rows(rows_iterator._table, start_index=start_row, max_results=RESULTS_SIZE)
```

I've tried to find a way to maybe persist the table in Python or set a long expiration time but I can't seem to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to solve it, by persisting the query results in a table using the query_job_config params in the query:

```
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    table_ref = self.blockchainDal.client.dataset(config.nft_database_name).table(results_table_name)
    job_config.destination =  table_ref
```